# Detect if ads are loaded

Tags: javascript, load

How do I detect if ads are loaded and redirect if not loaded ? Assuming I have a  tag and javascript is enabled, can this be tampered ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? If you're asking about detecting whether or not ad files stored on your website are downloaded by users, your question might be better suited at another Stack Exchange site like Webmasters or Server Fault.

Comment: You know, I think this is one of those questions whose purpose I consider so evil that I would never consider answering it.

Comment: i really can't see why this should be closed - it's a question related to programming ("how do is detect an adblocker" (the question here isn't clear, but i think this is meant)), and there's definetely an answer to this ("there's no safe way to do, but you could try several things" _is_ an answer, and i would relly like to clearyfy this anwer, which doesn't fit into a comment... just closing this also doesn't help Dheeraj to understand). please reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas come to mind. If there's no JavaScript enabled on the page, your ads probably won't load. So you could do something like this:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/noads" />
</noscript>
```

Some people have ad blockers, so that they can still have JS without ads. So you could create a variable in inline JS (`var ads_loaded = false;`), and then switch its value in the file that loads the ads (`load_ads(); ads_loaded = true;`). The idea is that, if the `ads_loaded` variable is changed, then everything else in the file was probably executed, as well.